# Sum of two columns showing wrong result tsql

Tags: t-sql

**I have query as**

```
select distinct 
EnglishProductCategoryName,
sum(isnull(fic.SalesAmount,0))InternetSalesAmount,
sum(isnull(frs.SalesAmount,0))ResellerSalesAmount

 from dimproduct dp   join DimProductSubcategory dps on dp.ProductSubcategoryKey=dps.ProductSubcategoryKey
                     join DimProductCategory dpc on dpc.ProductCategoryKey=dps.ProductCategoryKey
                     left join FactInternetSales fic on fic.ProductKey=dp.ProductKey
                     left join FactResellerSales frs on frs.ProductKey= dp.ProductKey

        group by EnglishProductCategoryName
```

but when I do

```
select sum(isnull(fis.SalesAmount,0))InternetSalesAmount from FactInternetSales 
select sum(isnull(frs.SalesAmount,0))resellerSalesAmount from FactResellerSales
```

and compare sum of  whole englishproductcategoryname and sum of internet sales amount,reseller sales amount should be same but its not same

Help will be appriciated
Thanks

Comment: Format your code.

Comment: Please post DDL+DML+expected result

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0):

Check for missing ProductSubcategory or ProductCategory

```
select distinct 
EnglishProductCategoryName,
sum(isnull(fic.SalesAmount,0))InternetSalesAmount,
sum(isnull(frs.SalesAmount,0))ResellerSalesAmount

 from dimproduct dp   left join DimProductSubcategory dps on dp.ProductSubcategoryKey=dps.ProductSubcategoryKey
                    left join DimProductCategory dpc on dpc.ProductCategoryKey=dps.ProductCategoryKey
                     left join FactInternetSales fic on fic.ProductKey=dp.ProductKey
                     left join FactResellerSales frs on frs.ProductKey= dp.ProductKey

        group by EnglishProductCategoryName
```